# Delimiters in the Base64 string which were not present when fetched from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, base64, blob, delimiter

I stored some images in MySQL database in blob format by converting the image into base64 string and want to display on the front end.

Base64 string where the delimiters are missing.

Image Storing in MySQL database but while retrieving from database using hql it is fetched as base64 string in a list but all the delimiters like ;,: were removed due to which it is not converted to an image. Can anyone suggest me the solution to the problem?[base64String in the list where the delimiters are removed by default which I fetched from MySQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hROki.png)

but the starting of the base64 string should be data:image/jpeg;base64, where :;, are missed in the image.

Comment: Did you try just to add data:image/jpeg;base64 like prefix

Comment: @Nikola Thank you but i should remove the existing dataimage/jpegnbase64... and then i should append data:image/jpeg;base64  can you guide me how to do that in javascript?

Comment: In js is very easy var newImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64" + DATA; but i see your screenshot and dataimage/jpegbase64 is bad format. Maybe is better to fix this on server side. Looks like MySql make some regular expression.